# Trigger an alert when a css-width-style animated with transitions reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a simple game where there are colored bars that slowly drop to zero. The player must click the "refill" button before any bar drops to zero or they lose. Initially I tried doing some time outs and things to try and just get the alerts to show up when needed, but they were showing up the second the width css style started its transition to 0, which isn't what I wanted. Even putting delays on it wasn't working.

So instead I started looking at the pixel width of the blueBar css style to try and trigger the alert when that is zero. I am able to get the alert to show up when I manually set the width to zero, but it doesn't seem to keep up with the changing width. Is there a way to get the variable blueWidth to continuously check its value so that an alert can be triggered when it equals 0?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Locate the main items in the page
  var blueButton = $('#blue-button');
  var blueBar = $('#blue-bar');
  var yellowButton = $('#yellow-button');
  var yellowBar = $('#yellow-bar');

  // triggers auto-decay of the blue bar
  blueBar.delay(2000).queue(function(){
      blueBar.css({'width': '0%', 'transition': 'width 5s linear'});
  });

  // refills blue bar on click, then auto-decay it after set timeout
  blueButton.click(function() {
      blueBar.css({'width': '100%', 'transition': 'width 0.5s linear'});
      setTimeout(function(){
          blueBar.css({'width': '0%', 'transition': 'width 5s linear'})
      }, 2000);
  });

  // checks to see if blue bar zeroes out
  var blueWidth = parseInt(blueBar.css('width').slice(0,-2));
  console.log(blueWidth);
  if(blueWidth <= 0){
      alert('you lose :(');
  }

  // triggers auto-decay of the yellow bar
  yellowBar.delay(3000).queue(function(){
      yellowBar.css({'width': '0%', 'transition': 'width 2.5s linear'});
  });

  // refills yellow bar on click, then auto-decay it after set timeout
  yellowButton.click(function() {
      yellowBar.css({'width': '100%', 'transition': 'width 0.5s linear'});
      setTimeout(function(){
          yellowBar.css({'width': '0%', 'transition': 'width 2.5s linear'})
      }, 3000);    
  });
  });
```

```css
.game {
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

.empty {
    width: 160px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.blue {
    width: 100%;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    background: #bfe5ff;
}

.yellow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    background: #f8d975;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game">
    <div>
        <div class="empty">
            <div id="blue-bar" class="blue"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="blue-button">refill</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="empty">
            <div id="yellow-bar" class="yellow"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="yellow-button">refill</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Locate the main items in the page
  var blueButton = $('#blue-button');
  var blueBar = $('#blue-bar');
  var yellowButton = $('#yellow-button');
  var yellowBar = $('#yellow-bar');

  // triggers auto-decay of the blue bar
  blueBar.delay(2000).queue(function() {
    blueBar.css({
      'width': '0%',
      'transition': 'width 5s linear'
    });
  });

  // refills blue bar on click, then auto-decay it after set timeout
  ;
  blueButton.click(function() {
    blueBar.css({
      'width': '100%',
      'transition': 'width 0.5s linear'
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      blueBar.css({
        'width': '0%',
        'transition': 'width 5s linear'
      })
    }, 2000);
  });

  // checks to see if blue bar zeroes out

  setInterval(function() {
    var blueWidth = parseInt(blueBar.css('width').slice(0, -2));
    if (blueWidth <= 0) {
      console.log('you lose because of blue:(');
    }
  }, 300);

  // triggers auto-decay of the yellow bar
  yellowBar.delay(3000).queue(function() {
    yellowBar.css({
      'width': '0%',
      'transition': 'width 2.5s linear'
    });
  });

  // refills yellow bar on click, then auto-decay it after set timeout
  yellowButton.click(function() {
    yellowBar.css({
      'width': '100%',
      'transition': 'width 0.5s linear'
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      yellowBar.css({
        'width': '0%',
        'transition': 'width 2.5s linear'
      })
    }, 3000);
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    var yellowWidth = parseInt(yellowBar.css('width').slice(0, -2));
    if (yellowWidth <= 0) {
      console.log('you lose because of yellow:(');
    }
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
.game {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.empty {
  width: 160px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background: #bfe5ff;
}

.yellow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background: #f8d975;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game">
  <div>
    <div class="empty">
      <div id="blue-bar" class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="blue-button">refill</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="empty">
      <div id="yellow-bar" class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="yellow-button">refill</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thought of the same solution when noticed that the condition was working fine but you beat me to it xD. +1

Comment: @Highdef faster ! haha :)

Comment: Awesome, that did it! I forgot intervals whe trying to work with timeouts :P I added a clearInterval to so it wouldn't keep refiring.